# Django queryset interpolation for a previous / next instance function

Tags: python, django, django-models

Writing a dry function that returns either previous or next instances of a given instance.

This function return previous instances:

```
def previous(instance):
    try:
        return Picture.objects.filter(id__lt=instance.id).first()
    except Picture.DoesNotExist:
        return instance
```

I want to create an abstracted function which returns either the previous or the next instance using an additional `gt_or_lt` argument. The problem lies in interpolating that argument into the `filter(id__gt_or_lt)`.

```
def seek_instance(gt_or_lt, instance):
    try:
        return Picture.objects.filter(id__gt_or_lt=instance.id).first()
    except Picture.DoesNotExist:
        return instance
```

I've tried:

```
return Picture.objects.filter(id__gt_or_lt = instance.id).first()
seek_instance("gt", instance)
```

```
return Picture.objects.filter(id__f"{gt_or_lt}" = instance.id).first()
seek_instance("gt", instance)
```

```
return Picture.objects.filter(f"{gt_or_lt}" = instance.id).first()
```

```
return Picture.objects.filter(gt_or_lt = instance.id).first()
seek("id__gt", instance)
```

All fail with their respective errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary with kwargs expansion.

```
return Picture.objects.filter(**{f"id__{gt_or_lt}": instance.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary expansion, like [@DanielRoseman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794558/67579) suggests. But that will still not per se render the previous, or next item. If for example the model has an [**`ordering`** option [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering), then it is possible that the order is different than on the `id`. Furthermore, for the previous one, you will need to reverse the ordering.

Furthermore depending on the situation, you might want to prevent that `seek_instance` can be given a different lookup, like `'in'` for example.

We can thus use an `if … elif … else` here to branch on the item we wish to retrieve, and raise a `ValueError` in case you use some other lookup:

```
def seek_instance(lt_or_gt, instance):
    try:
        if lt_or_gt == 'lt':
            return Picture.objects.filter(pk__lt=instance.pk).order_by('-pk').first()
        elif lt_or_gt == 'gt':
            return Picture.objects.filter(pk__gt=instance.pk).order_by('pk').first()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Should be 'lt' or 'gt'")
    except Picture.DoesNotExist:
        return instance
```

Comment: Interesting. I see that you've imported Q but I don't see where it's used in the function. I'm probably missing something very obvious as I'm only vaguely familiar with Q.

Comment: @PersonPr7: sorry, that was something for another answer. The `Q` is not necessary here :)